# Set Implementation Equals Method Always returns false

Tags: java, set

One of my methods is not working in my Java implementation of the `Set` class. Why does `equals` always return `false`?

```
public boolean equals(Set<E> s) {   
    if(this.size() == s.size()){
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
            if(theData[i] == s.get(i)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My set is `Set<Integer>` and I've compared a set of (1,2,3,4) and (1,2,3,4) together and it outputs `false`.

EDIT: All of my sets are ordered from least to greatest.

EDIT2: Here is my code dealing with equals in the main driver

```
    else if(spaceSplit[0].equals("equal")){
            if(spaceSplit.length == 3){ 
                String fSet = spaceSplit[1];
                String sSet = spaceSplit[2];

                int fSetIndex = 0;
                int sSetIndex = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < sets.size(); i++){
                    if(((Set<Integer>) sets.get(i)).getName().equals(fSet)){
                        fSetIndex = i;
                    }
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < sets.size(); i++){
                    if(((Set<Integer>) sets.get(i)).getName().equals(sSet)){
                        sSetIndex = i;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(sets.get(fSetIndex).equals(sets.get(sSetIndex)));

            } else {
                System.out.println("Parameters entered wrong, please try again.");
            }
```

EDIT3: In my program I've been messing with it, and it outputs false everytime I put a real set in. If I just made up 2 sets that don't exist and call the equals method, it outputs `true`. I'm so confused.

EDIT4: Here's more of the set code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Set<E extends Comparable> {

private String name;
private int size = 0;
private E[] theData;
private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 100;
private int capacity = 0;

public Set() {
    capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    theData = (E[]) new Integer[capacity];
}

public Set(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    theData = (E[]) new Integer[capacity];
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private void reallocate() {
    capacity = 2 * capacity;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `theData[i]`? Shouldn't it be `this.get(i)`?

Comment: @Jonathan `theData[i]` is the array I store all my set's values in. So it's essentially the same as doing this.get(i) right?

Comment: Multiple problems: You'll instantly `return true` if any elements match. You're assuming that the elements are in the same order, which you haven't specified is a property of your implementation. You are using `==` instead of `equals`. Perhaps most immediately relevant, you're not overriding `Object#equals(Object)`; always use `@Override`.

Comment: Another problem: since your argument is `Set<E>`, there's no guarantee that it will be your class.  It could be any `Set` including a `HashSet`, and now you have no way to know what order `s.get(i)` will return things in.

Comment: @chrylis I changed my if statement to be `theData[i].equals(s.get(i))` now, and I have it so my sets go from smallest to largest ordered. So basically I just made an assumption. The second part about overriding I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @ajb Since he has a `get` method, it appears that `java.util.Set` isn't involved.

Comment: @chrylis Correct. I built my own Set class and am trying to implement it. Everything works besides this equals method.

Comment: Try annotating your method with `@Override` and see what happens.

Comment: @chrylis when I do that it tells me that I must override or implement a supertype method.

Comment: @chrylis when I enter in 2 sets that aren't even there it returns true. What could be causing that?

Comment: @CSGuy94 It was pretty confusing to use the name of a common Java runtime class and not make it clear that this is your own class with the same name.  Don't do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you aren't overriding `equals()`

The signature is not

```
public boolean equals(Set<E>)
```

It is

```
public boolean equals(Object)
```

That is why when you add the `@Override` annotation you get a compiler error.  You must use Object as the parameter, then check for `instanceof` and cast.

Answer (score 0):

The compare should be .equals instead of ==.

Comment: Thanks, I made the correction, but it still outputs false for everything.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
public boolean equals(Set<E> s) {   
    if(this.size() == s.size()){
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
           if(!this.get(i).equals(s.get(i))){
              return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried that with 2 sets of `(1,2,3,4)` but it outputted false again.

Comment: when I enter in 2 sets that aren't even there it returns true. What could be causing that?